# Linear tranformation with mirroring and then depiction on S(u)+(1,1,1) x S(u)

Tags: linear-transformations

English is not my first language so I apologize for any mistakes.

Question:

Find the matrix for the linear transformation F in the room that is defined by $\vec{u}$ first mirroring in x+z=0 and then have the mirror image $S(\vec{u})$ depicted on $S(\vec{u})+(1,1,1)$ x $S(\vec{u})$.

I solved the mirroring fairly easily and got: 
$\begin{pmatrix} 0 &0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Which means that $S(\vec{u})= \begin{pmatrix}z \\ -y \\ x \end{pmatrix}$

Now comes the part that I'm not completly sure with. What I did was taking the cross product between $S(\vec{u})+(1,1,1)$ x $S(\vec{u})$ which is 
$\vec{v}=\begin{pmatrix}x+y \\ z-x \\ -y-z \end{pmatrix}$ then take the scalar product between $\vec{v}$ and $S(\vec{u})$ for the angle (which is $90^\circ$) and rotate around the z-axis.

This gives me:  $\begin{pmatrix} 0 &-1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$

and my final answer would then be:
$\begin{pmatrix} 0 &-1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ 
$\begin{pmatrix} 0 &0 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$=
$\begin{pmatrix} 0 &1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix}$

Unfortunately I have no way of controlling my answer and I feel like I'm completely wrong.

Answer (score 1):

1) why does S(u) do anything to the y, component in the reflection?

Where do the principle component vectors go?

Assume $u = (1,0,0)$, then $S(u) = (0,0,1)$

$(1,1,1)\times (0,0,1) = (1,-1,0)\\
S(u) + (1,1,1)\times S(u) = (1,-1,1)$

Your final matrix must take $u$ to $F(u)$

$\begin {bmatrix} 1\\-1\\1 \end{bmatrix}$ must be the first column of $F$

Now do this for the other components.

Alternatives...

$S(u)+ (1,1,1)\times S(u) = (I + (1,1,1)\times I)S(u)$

$\left(\begin{bmatrix} 1\\&1\\&&1\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} 0&-1&1\\1&0&-1\\-1&1&0\end{bmatrix}\right)\begin{bmatrix} &&1\\&1\\1\end{bmatrix}$

Alternative 2.

$u = (x,y,z)\\
S(u) = (z,y,x)\\
(1,1,1)\times (z,y,x) = (x-y,z-x,y-z)\\
S(u)+(x-y,x-z,y-z) = (x-y+z, -x+y+z,x+y-z)$

Comment: Thank you for your comment :)

I calculated the S(u) with: $2Proj_(1,0,1)(x,y,z)-(x,y,z)$ but that is probably wrong.
An other mistake I made was with how I calculated the cross product.

In alternativ 2:
The matrix would then be $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & -1 & 1 \\ -1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}$ is thar right?

Comment: That is what I have.